# Puzzle. WPF host in winform - bug with string containing "_"

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Hosting WPF in winform is explained here [Walkthrough: Hosting a WPF Composite Control in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215.aspx). I explain the problem in the most simple way: just create a winform project. Then I create another project WPF User Control Library. On User control library I add one button and name it button1. Then in xaml.cs file i create one public function which looks like this:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void SetText(string text)
    {
        button1.Content = text;
    }
}
```

I add that project as a reference in winform so I can add control to my winform. In winform I add one button and create button onClick event. The code looks like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wpfButton.SetText("asd 12_2_a_s");
    }
}
```

And now the party begins. I compile the project and the final looks like that:
[image]

So if I click on left button, on right button there should show string looks like this: "asd 12_2_a_s". But, what is happening is always first "_" is missing. That I get this:
[image]

The primitive solution that problem is just to write doubles "__" wpfButton.SetText("asd 12__2__a__s");
And that works. But my question is: Is this is actual bug or I missing something?

Comment: press Alt Key and see if that underscore re appears under digit `1` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underscore in the text/content of a control is a character used to indicate the access key. You can escape it by using a double underscore __

`"t__est"`

<strike>Haven't tested this, but you also could use the @ sign.</strike> `@"t_est"` will output `t_est`

EDIT: @ Doesn't work for setting Text/Content Properties.

Comment: @Habib Yep, discovered that now. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Didn't think of that, that this is an character used to indicate the access key.